# How to make yarn fully deterministic?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

On [the Yarn blog](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/05/31/determinism/) they say:

> Yarn is fully deterministic as long as all your teammates are using the same Yarn version.

Requiring everyone be using the same version seems like a pretty big limitation.

When using [Gradle](https://gradle.org) they have [the Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html), which is stored in source control and ensures that everyone building with the wrapper gets the same version of Gradle *regardless of what version of Gradle is installed locally*.

Is there anything like this for yarn? How can we make our yarn invocations similarly deterministic, regardless of what version of yarn/node/npm are installed locally?

We've tried using the [Gradle node plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md), which uses Gradle to sort of bootstrap node, npm, and yarn (installing copies local to the repo), but it doesn't seem to work at all on some of the machines we've tried it on.

Answer (score 1):

**Yarn** always has that limitation and nothing can be done about it. But if you are using NPM then you can.

**NPM** now enforces the same workflow as yarn (and many other package managers). It generates `package-lock.json` to know what exact versions your project uses.

And npm has a solid advantage since it is fully deterministic across npm versions than yarn has across different versions of yarn.

Comment: I don't understand the advantage in your last sentence. It looks like there may be a typo.

Comment: I am saying that, npm is fully deterministic across all its versions unlike `yarn` which is only deterministic if using the same verion. Also, `npm` is moving in a right direction (say hi to `pip`). It is pretty great already, but soon it will be even cooler. So better use npm

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the `yarn.lock` file was introduce on purpose to make an installation "deterministic". Therefore having a locally working project means that the related lock file can be safely shipped to new environments and still produce the same dependancies installation.

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/